# Can a Makefile have a dependency on the result of a shell script?

Tags: shell, makefile

Is there a way to use the return value of a shell script as a dependency in a Makefile?

For example:

Makefile:

```
proj: getsource.sh
    cc src1.c src2.c ...
getsource.sh: checksource.sh
    wget http://www.something.com/src1.c
```

checksource.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
# bash pseudo code because I can never remember bash's syntax
if [[ -not -exists src1.c ]]
    exit 1
else
    exit 0
...
```

When executed without the source present, the Makefile would run the getsource.sh target, then the proj target. If the source is present, it would only run the proj target.

Comment: Are you sure you want the behavior to depend on the *return value* of the script, and not its *output?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, Makefile rules only depend on the date of local files.  Therefore, unfortunately, you have to do something like what @xbug showed, and in the more generic case:

```
file-I-care-about.ext: .some-precondition.dep
     run-command > file-I-care-about.ext

.some-precondition.dep:
     run-some-logic && touch .some-precondition.dep
```

For instance, I want to make sure I have a utility I need installed, but this completely generalizes to any conditions you want to assert:

```
# Generate README from my source file
README.md: src1.cc .extractor-installed.dep
    mdextract src1.cc > $@

# Install doc extractor if it's not already installed
.extractor-installed.dep:
    which mdextract && touch $@ || npm install -g mdextract && touch $@
```

`which mdextract` is my "validation logic" and if it passes, I update the dependency, but otherwise I run the expensive command and then update the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

What about just doing this:

```
proj: src1.c src2.c  # ...
    cc src1.c src2.c  # ...

src1.c:
    @echo "retrieving src1.c ..."
    @wget http://www.something.com/src1.c
```

Comment: Getting some source online was only meant as a simple example. I'm more interested if make has this functionality.